# Equivalent to 'from module import *' but including private members

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a git repo that has a python module defining a few classes, some of which are private.  I'm using that git repo as a git submodule elsewhere and want to add a new python module with the same name and a few more classes.

The idea is something like:

repo1/module.py:

```
class _foo:
    def __init__(self, _arguments_):
         #dostuff

class bar(_foo):
    def __init__(self, _arguments_):
         #dostuff
```

repo2/module.py:

```
class baz(_foo):
    def __init__(self, _arguments_):
        #dostuff
```

What I'm stuck on is how to correctly handle the importing in repo2/module.py so that I can use _foo as the super for baz, but also allow importing of repo2/module to provide access to bar.

If I start repo2/module.py with:

```
from repo1.module import *
```

I don't get _foo available to use as a super, but I do get bar available when repo2/module.py is imported elsewhere.  On the other hand I could do:

```
from repo1 import module as mod
```

and then I have mod._foo available to use as the super, but I don't get bar available for use elsewhere.

Is there a way to do something equivalent to 
`from module import *` 
that also includes private members, or should I do something like

```
from module import *
from module import _foo
```

or is there something nicer/better/safer/cleaner?  If it makes a difference, I dislike `from module import *` and would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Python modules and Git modules have *nothing at all* to do with each other. Please be more cautious around tagging.

Comment: ...as for the actual question -- note that wildcard imports are considered a code smell in general. I would strongly advise against using them in the first place; `mod.bar` is preferable to just `bar`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
I added the git-submodule tag because I'm using and extending a git-submodule, but I'll consider that in the future.

mod.bar is what I'd prefer, but it's getting everything available in relevant name spaces that's the issue.

Comment: Why don't you do ``from module import _foo, bar``? Why use the ``*`` import at all?

Comment: If you need to export the names, they shouldn't be private in the first place, by definition.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi because there's a lot of members and the list is likely to increase

Comment: @snakecharmerb they need to be private, not protected.  They're things I need in subclasses that get defined in a separate file.